# Discord.js My bot can't find any parent or children channel when hosted on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

Ok so i'm using Discord.js v12.4, and basically one command includes a 'category.children.forEach(...)', and it works fine locally. But when it's online, category.children returns an empty collection, and no channel has a parent, always null.

I did a 'guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => console.log(channel.parent));' to check, and always null, null, null... Same with children...

Why would Heroku got trouble with children and parent channels ?

The original part of script (**works locally**) :

```
    let channels = [];
    let v_channels = [];
    modelCategory.children.forEach((channel) => {
        if(channel.type === "voice") v_channels[channel.position] = channel;
        else channels[channel.position] = channel;
    });
    channels = channels.concat(v_channels);
    console.log(channels);
```

But when the bot is hosted online :

```
>> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick update : I can no longer get parent and channel locally too.